# How to add new key/value in existing array of SequelizeInstance object in Node/Express Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Node
I'm trying to add new key/value in array

This is my array and now i'm trying to add value in new data like

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "ABC",
  "description": "ABC Details"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "title": "PQR",
  "description": "PQR Details"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "title": "XYZ",
  "description": "XYZ Details"
}]

for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  data[index].info = "New info";
}

console.log(data);
```

But when i access the "data" array outside for loop cant get added 'info' in data array

Comment: I converted your code to a live demo and it doesn't appear to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: In for loop i tried with this also => data[index]['info'] = "Details"; but still no success

Comment: What do you mean "still no success"? The existing code **is** successful.

Comment: i'm not getting info key **outside forloop**

Comment: The `console.log` I added in the demo **is** outside the for loop

Comment: is that same work for `object SequelizeInstance`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233012/discussion-between-harshad-dusane-and-quentin).

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault its not array it;s SequelizeInstance object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was SequelizeInstance so solution is

```
for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
   data[index] = data[index].toJSON();
   data[index].info = 'my info';
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
data.forEach((item) => {
  item.info = "New info"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

this should work.
How did you try to access 'info'?

```js
console.log(data[0].info) // New info
```